# Cyanogenmod/LineageOS repo sync error

Tags: git, synchronization, cyanogenmod, repo

i synced the whole LineageOS cm-14.1 branch but right at the end it throws this error.

```
error: unable to create file frontend/client/src/autotest/public/Open+Sans:300.woff (Invalid argument)
error: unable to create file frontend/client/src/autotest/public/Roboto+Bold:700.woff (Invalid argument)
error: unable to create file frontend/client/src/autotest/public/Roboto+Light:300.woff (Invalid argument)
error: unable to create file frontend/client/src/autotest/public/Roboto+Medium:500.woff (Invalid argument)
error: unable to create file frontend/client/src/autotest/public/Roboto+Regular:400.woff (Invalid argument)
error: unable to create file server/site_tests/display_EdidStress/test_data/edids/weekly/SCT_272_STEELCASE_m:s_HDMI.txt (Invalid argument)
Checking out files: 100% (8423/8423), done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/r/Ubuntu/LineageOS/.repo/repo/main.py", line 531, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/mnt/r/Ubuntu/LineageOS/.repo/repo/main.py", line 507, in _Main
    result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
  File "/mnt/r/Ubuntu/LineageOS/.repo/repo/main.py", line 180, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "/mnt/r/Ubuntu/LineageOS/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 821, in Execute
    project.Sync_LocalHalf(syncbuf, force_sync=opt.force_sync)
  File "/mnt/r/Ubuntu/LineageOS/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1327, in Sync_LocalHalf
    self._InitWorkTree(force_sync=force_sync)
  File "/mnt/r/Ubuntu/LineageOS/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2486, in _InitWorkTree
    raise GitError("cannot initialize work tree")
error.GitError: cannot initialize work tree
```

I already tried to delete the extrernal/autotest folders in the .repo folder to force it to resync and I also reintialized the repo.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a file contains preserved character in WSL is not supported currently.
See https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1514 for detail.

By the way, you didn't mentioned that you are using WSL, this would make your question confused.